# Override environment variables in jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, jasmine

I have a Angular service that looks something like this:

```
import {environment} from '../environment'
```

....

```
public something() {
 if(environment.production)
 {
   // do stuf
 } else {
  // do something else 
 }
}
```

Now i want to test both cases (dev and prod environemnt). How do I "mock" when the environment is imported ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i came up with a solution where I didn't have to check for the environment in my service:

I used the `useFactory`:

```
NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Service,
      useFactory: (httpClient: HttpClient) => {
        if (environment.production) {
          return new MyCustomService(httpClient);
        } else {
          return new Service();
        }
      },
      deps: [HttpClient],
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

This way i manage which service is provided when the application is started up